# Publish subscribe and a dynamic topology

Tags: c#, wcf, servicestack, publish-subscribe

Im looking for tools to implementing a pub sub / event system . We have a challenging requirement where vehicles create a dynamic wifi network which the vehicles and other devices will use ( the vehicles have access points) . Also  if they are close to the office they need to communicate and send/relay messages to the office and corporate WAN .

**Dynamic topology.**

- No central point / server .. all/any vehicle can be a message broker/router all
  vehicles are clients.
- No central point of failure .
- Vehicles may form multiple groups which communicate amongst themselves if there is no connectivity between groups.
- Address of vehicle may be unknown  until it identifies itself  ( so
  vehicles need to ping all vehicles and see if they are reachable and
  if it can find one it needs to identify itself ).
- Part of the system ( office and WAN)  will be different networks.
- The vehicles and hence computers switch off 3-4 times per day.

We do not need 100% reliability , 98-99% of packets when in good network conditions would be fine. Performance requirement is not high eg 1 message per minute.

Must support Soap/XML standard for 3rd parties to connect into the system though this maybe a secondary binding.

There is a lot of theory on this but are there any tools to help us ?  I'm looking for C# as there will be quite a bit of customization and prefer solutions with no persistence or DBs / queues .

So far the best i can see is to use WS-Eventing and use Roman Kiss example ( on code project)  which is built on WCF ( and which i have used commercially before) . Then build a system which creates subscriptions ( and hence routes and relays) based on dynamic discovery  ( pings and "im here and here are my known neigbours"  messages) .

Comment: Why is this tagged ServiceStack? Are you wanting use this as part of the solution? As this isn't clear in the question the relevance here.

Comment: Happy for C# solutions including ServiceStack or WCF

Comment: You asking for something like omnet++ but for C#?

Comment: Yes but for real networks